# Dataframe from tuples with transposition

Tags: python

I don't understand what I would need to change from the code below in order to transpose the matrix elements.
This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

a = ('1', ['x','y'])
b = ('2', ['d','t'])

lst = [a, b]

df=pd.DataFrame(lst)
df
```

The result is the following:

[image]

Instead I would need to get the following result:

[image]

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `zip` to tack the matrix rows together:

```py
pd.DataFrame(zip(a[1], b[1]), columns=[a[0], b[0]])
```